# How not to redirect the server name to an application?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, bind

In the domain file "db.myplace.mydomain.com" I configured a name for the reverse proxy (proxy.myplace.mydomain.com) and a name for a web application (myapp.myplace.mydomain.com). However, when I type the name of the proxy in a browser, the name of myapp is returned to me. I don't want the proxy name to return anything in the browser. How can I configure this?

Settings in the db.myplace.mydomain.com file:

```
proxy                   IN  A       192.168.0.20
myapp                   IN  CNAME   proxy
```

Settings in the sites-available/myapp.conf file:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name         myapp.myplace.mydomain.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.key;

    # security
    include             nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.250:8080;
        include    nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name myapp.myplace.mydomain.com;
    return      301 https://myapp.myplace.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to setup a separate server block for server_name proxy.myplace.mydomain.com and redirect it to nothing, either via an actual redirect, or just have it return a standard HTTP status code (more on that below).

It would look something like this..

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxy.myplace.mydomain.com;
    return <code>;
}
```

Code could be any normal HTTP codes, but these may be good:

- 204: No Content
- 403: Forbidden
- 405: Method Not Allowed
- 410: Gone
- 418: [I'm a teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_418)
- 444: No Response
- 501: Not Implemented
- 503: Service Unavailable

So if you wanted to implement code 444 (No Response), you'd add this..

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxy.myplace.mydomain.com;
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: If i have other sites each configured in a different ".conf" file would this work? Would it be better to create a conf file just for "proxy.myplace.mydomain.com"?

Comment: Should be fine, as long as you have declared server_name for them. And yes, probably not a bad idea to create a separate conf just for it.

Comment: I set up a separate proxy.conf file and it worked. I'll see if I can block it by firewall too.

Comment: Proceed carefully attempting to block by firewall. You have multiple A records for different domains and subdomains pointing to that same server, and stateful firewalls are predominant, meaning they base things on IP, port, protocol, etc. Trying to block port 80 will affect more than just a single server declaration.

Comment: I just noticed a problem. If I type https://proxy.myplace.mydomain.com it is also directed to https://myapp.myplace.mydomain.com. The return 444 should be for http and https.

Comment: Just make a second server block for HTTPS then - replace 80 with 443.